# Self Reference when serializing nested Object

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, entity-framework-core

I want to store a snapshot of a nested model in my database as sort of a change history.
Therefore I made a model that serializes the whole object into a JSON string for easier storage.

Simplified `Data` class I want to store:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DataObject> DataObject { get; set; }
}
```

The `DataObject` for the collection inside `Data`:

```
public class DataObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeMoreInfo { get; set; }
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    public virtual Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

My snapshot class looks something like this:

```
public class DataHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string _Data;

    [NotMapped]
    public Data Data
    {
        get { return _Data == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(_Data); }
        set { _Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value , Formatting.Indented, 
                new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my controller I do:

```
var data = await _repo.GetData(id);
var historyEntry = new DataHistory();
historyEntry.Data= data;
_repo.Add(historyEntry);
```

`GetData()` method inside the repository:

```
public async Task<Data> GetData(int id)
{
   return await _context.Data
   .Include(d => d.DataObject)
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == id);
}
```

The problem is when I try to serialize one `Data` entry I get a self reference inside the `DataObject` so it includes the `Data` object again and also the `DataObjects`. Even with `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`
the produced JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1051,
  "SomeInfo": "asdasd",
  "DataObject": [
    {
      "Id": 121,
      "SomeMoreInfo": "asdasd",
      "Data": {
        "Id": 1051,
        "SomeInfo": "asdasd",
        "DataObject": [
          {
            "Id": 122,
            "SomeMoreInfo": "asdasd",
            "DataId": 1051
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Id": 122,
      "SomeMoreInfo": "asdasd",
      "Data": {
        "Id": 1051,
        "SomeInfo": "asdasd",
        "DataObject": [
          {
            "Id": 121,
            "SomeMoreInfo": "asdasd",
            "DataId": 1051
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:** Expected output would be something like this:

```
{
    "Id": 1051,
    "SomeInfo": "Data",
    "DataObject": [
        {
            "Id": 121,
            "SomeMoreInfo": "DataObject1"
            "DataId": 1051
        },
        {
            "Id": 122,
            "SomeMoreInfo": "DataObject2"
            "DataId": 1051
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I stop it from including `Data` a second time without using DTOs?

**EDIT:**

If I try it without Entity Framework, `ReferenceLoopHandling.None` works as expected. See Dotnet Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/bmAoAW.
So there seems to be a problem with my EF Core configuration or something.

Comment: Set `PreserveReferencesHandling` to `PreserveReferencesHandling.All`

Comment: @Alberto This doesn't solve the problem. Now i just get $ref everywhere in a bigger entity, and its even worse because it serializes the GrandChildren first so i get all the $ref in the original DataObject Array ... So the Reference Loop is actually still there. If I don't use EF ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore works as expected and doesn't include the reference at all.

Comment: What if you put `[JsonIgnore]` on the `Data` property inside your `DataObject` class?

Comment: @BrianRogers what if i only query the DataObject at some point? Then I'm not getting the Reference to the the Data right ? Feels like i need to use DTOs

Comment: So you only want `DataObject.Data` to be ignored when it is serialized inside `DataHistory.Data`?

Comment: @BrianRogers Exactly. In the real code both objects are more complex than this example here and using DTOs would mean a lot of edits to the code base. So i was hoping to get around this with the right serialization

Comment: You can probably use a custom ContractResolver to do that then.  Let me see if I can come up with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in the comments that effectively you want to `DataObject.Data` property to be ignored whenever you are serializing `Data` from within `DataHistory`.  You can do this by using a custom `ContractResolver` to ignore the property programmatically.

Here is the code you would need for the resolver:

```
public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (prop.DeclaringType == typeof(DataObject) && prop.PropertyName == nameof(DataObject.Data))
        {
            prop.Ignored = true;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Then apply it within the `JsonSerializerSettings` in `DataHistory.Data`:

```
    set { _Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value , Formatting.Indented, 
            new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None
            });
    }
```

Comment: This actually works! Do you know why ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore doesn't work in this case though? Is it because EF actually proxies the entities ? Just trying to understand this.

Comment: Without being able to see a full reproducible example where it is not working, I can only speculate.  Maybe you somehow have a longer chain in EF than you have in your example:  Data1 -> DataObject1 -> Data2 -> DataObject2 -> Data1?  So in that case, the reference loop would not be detected until you encounter Data1 a second time, whereas just ignoring the Data property cuts it off right away.

Comment: This explanation just pointed me to a completely different part of the codebase.  I think the AutoMapper mapping is the actual problem. The original model is getting mapped with all its properties and children but never actually stored and I'm guessing this is why EF doesn't detect the circular reference

Comment: Well, yes I just confirmed my suspicion: The original object was mapped with Automapper and the children were also mapped but i'm guessing those are not the same objects and therfore the references get lost. If i Serialize the original Model (that has lots of unneccesary data) it is serialized the way i was expecting it. Thanks Brian for providing a solution to my self made problem and pointing me to the real culprit :)

Comment: No problem; glad I could help!